# Converting checkpoints generated to .weights darkflow

Tags: tensorflow, darkflow

I have done customized training using Darkflow and yolov2.weights. There are four files in checkpoint folder.These are:

```
1.yolov2-3c-5500.data-00000-of-00001
2.yolov2-3c-5500.index
3.yolov2-3c-5500.meta
4.yolov2-3c-5500.profile
```

I want to convert these file .weights?

Currently the checkpoint are loaded like this:

```
options = {
    'model': 'cfg/yolov2-4c.cfg',
    'load': 5500,
    'threshold': 0.3,
    'gpu':1.0

}
```

I want to load 'load' key as .weights file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trained checkpoint files `yolov2-3c-5500.data` file is actually your weight file. If you want to convert to .pb file, use the below command

```
flow --model cfg/Your_ConfigFile.cfg --load ckpt/Your_required_checkpoint-chkptNumber --savepb
```

Ex: flow --model cfg/Your_ConfigFile.cfg --load 5500 --savepb

Comment: if you look at your ckpt folder, inside you will find the data, meta , profile files, so for your case probably `flow --model cfgyolov2-3c.cfg --load ckpt/yolov2-3c-5500 --savepb`

Comment: One more question after converting into .pb format will I be able to load weights in the following way:  load =bin/yolov2-3c-5500.pb?

Comment: @sultan, to test your pb files for object detection, use this command  `flow --pbLoad built_graph/yolo.pb --metaLoad built_graph/yolo.meta --imgdir sample_img/`  Paste your images in the sample_img directory

Comment: Thanks for your answer,But I wanted to know is there any way to convert this into a single file.Here I can see that two files i s being used '.pb' and '.meta'.I wan to test this on real time video.

Comment: pb files have your weights information, you can use these to perform your object detection on video feed. meta file is just a json representation of it. Use openCv video capture to read in the frames data, for each frame, use `TFNet` `return_predict(frame)` method to see your results

Comment: When running this command,python flow --model cfg/yolov2-3c.cfg --load ckpt/yolov2-3c-5500 --savepb, I am getting this error :AssertionError: ckpt/yolov2-3c-5500 not found

Comment: I got solution,the error was in loading the ckpt folder,the correct command will be 'python flow --model cfg/yolov2-3c.cfg --load 5500 --savepb'